# Nvidia 1080 GTX low performance issue with 390 driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

We searched the internet for several days and we found no suitable answers for our problem.

We develop in the company 3D cross-platform applications. We easily reach 60 FPS on windows 10 & ubuntu, using GTX 1060/1050.

We recently bought a MSI with a GTX 1080 8GB, working well but we hardly reach 15 FPS on our app.

We tested several things, ensured that the correct driver is loaded & used, disabled nouveau, tweaked nvidia-settings... Nothing seems to work.

Having a look at the nvidia-smi command, we can see that it recognizes our application and uses memory from the GPU, but the amount is very low compared to the other working cases (approximately 50% less than on our ubuntu working machines).

Do you have any clues on this kind of issue so we could keep investigating?

Cheers,

Edit 1 :

We installed the 390 Nvidia driver using sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall, which installed the recommended driver

We also tested only the nouveau driver and it is surprisingly better than the 390 (25 FPS)

EDIT 2 : Ubuntu Version : 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: Unless we can duplicate your exact environment, we may not be able to help you.  You might have better success with one of the programming sites here like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ that might have better success in the way that a driver interacts with an application.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. We are completely sure that this is a driver problem since we reach 25 FPS with nouveau driver and only 15 with the nvidia. Has anyone already encountered this kind of issue ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1100643/edit) your question and add details of how you installed the "correct" driver into your system.  However, it should be the same driver as with the other GTX 1060/1050 that you have tried.

Comment: Thank you, I edited our post. Feel free to ask for further info.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?  Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 have different installation steps.

Comment: We are using ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, we found out a month ago that a piece of code was not running well on this machine.

The VSync was hard coded and forced the whole program to reach only 15 FPS. Setting it to false solved the issue.

it's weird that the settings inside nvidia-settings did not affect anything (especially the VSync checkbox). Anyway it's working so thanks everybody ;)